# Is it possible to pass !important as parameter/option for LESSCSS mixins?

Tags: css, less

This is what I already have:

```
.coloring(@color){
    color:@color;
}
```

---

But this is what I actually wanted to do:

```
.coloring(@color, @important:''){
    color:@color @important;
    //etc 
}
```

So I could call:

```
.coloring(@color, !important);
```

But I get the error message "ParseError: Unrecognised input"

---

**Is there a way to tell this mixin optoinally to use "!important" for the CSS statements?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [The !important keyword](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-the-important-keyword). E.g. can just use `.coloring(red) !important;` w/o mixin changes.
Or use escaping for the modified mixin since `!` is not allowed symbol in mixin parameter values (i.e. `.coloring(red, ~'!important');`).

Also note that the default value of `''` for the `@important` parameter is not correct since the mixin call with this parameter omitted will result in invalid `color: color '';` CSS (use `@important...` or `@important: ~''` if you need an "empty" default value ).

P.S. Also do not miss that you can supply both color and `!important` values as a single parameter, i.e. `.coloring(red ~'!important');` would be also correct method to invoke your original 1-parameter mixin (if you need only `color` property to have the `!important` modifier contrary to `.coloring(red) !important;` syntax where `!important` applies to all CSS properties within the mixin).