# How to declare a variable as !important with LESS?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to have a variable declared as `!important` with LESS? Currently, I am getting a syntax error with the following.

**For example:**

```
@fontColor: #000000 !important;

p {
    color: @fontColor;
}
```

**Should render as:**

```
p {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

I know there is a way of escaping that is mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937061/1799136), using the following:

```
@fontColor: #000000 ~'!important';
```

There was talk about implementing it as simple syntax quite a while ago like my first example, just not to sure if they ever did - https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1401

Using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4)

Comment: It works for me with CodeKit, which is kept up with the latest less, your compiler is older

Comment: @Christina - Odd. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4)

Comment: @hsoto - Because it's easier to manage an entire C# project with the LESS/CSS JS, HTML and C# files all in one solution and program.

Comment: as far as i understand is issue you mention (https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1401) not talking about the `!important` syntax in a variable declaration, but about the option to define variables with importance (not overwritten with the last declaration wins rule).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your declaration of `@fontColor: #000000 !important;` indeed make no sense, what do you assign? a string, a list of something?
Most reasonable it a string, which should quoted and indeed escaped when used:

For that reason the following code seems correct (for me)

```
@fontColor: "#000000 !important";

p {
    color: ~"@{fontColor}";
}
```

I also found that the following code:

```
@wrong: red noncolor;
selector {
property: @wrong;
}

@wrongtoo: red !important;
selector {
propertytoo: @wrongtoo;
}
```

output:

```
selector {
  property: red noncolor;
}
selector {
  propertytoo: red;
}
```

The compiler (Less v2) does not throw a error in both cases. But in the second case `!important` is not compiled in the CSS code. Also `red !noncolor` compiles into the CSS code. Probably `!important` is some kind of keyword, but for me it seems an [inconsequence in the compiler](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2286https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2286) for now.

Also notice that the docs describe how to use `!important` with mixins at http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-the-important-keyword

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26875290/1064325) didn't work for me (I guess it was due to version, maybe).

What worked was [the workaround mentioned in OP's question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26855528/1064325), which I didn't see at first.

In case it happens to someone else, just try the following:

```
// !important doesn't work
@fontColor: #000000 !important;

// !important works!
@fontColor: #000000 ~'!important';
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937061/1064325)

Answer (score -2):

The correct way is

```
@fontColor: "#000000 ";

p {
    color: @fontColor !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Now do you really think that `color: "#000000 " !important;` is a valid CSS statement? All browsers will ignore it.